# Retrieve data more than the threshold limit

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml, ecmascript-5, csom

I want to override the QueryThrottle Setting using SPQueryThrottleOption. This is to be done in Client Object Model.

```
SPQuery q = new SPQuery();

q.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

Can be done in Client Object Model-Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["BigList"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
litMessage.Text = String.Format("This list contains {0} items", items.Count);
```

The important bit is the 4th line down:

query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;

The SPQueryThrottleOption enumeration has three values: Default, Override, and Strict. If you use the default value, the standard list view threshold applies to all users except local server administrators, who are not bound by either threshold. If you set the query throttle mode to Override, users who have the required permissions in the Web application user policy can query at the higher "auditors and administrators" threshold. Local server administrators remain unbound by either threshold. Finally, if you set the query throttle mode to Strict, this closes down the local server administrator loophole and the standard list view threshold applies to all users.

Comment: Hi,

I want to do the same in CSOM.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible in the client object model.